# Why read_excel() can't read xlsx from sftp server?

Tags: python, pandas, sftp, paramiko

When I try to read CSV from `sftp` server with `read_csv()` there is no problem at all. But when I try to read `xlsx` with `read_excel()` it never finishes reading file. I tried downloading from sftp and reading `xlsx`. It works well. But I didn't understand why I can't read from `sftp` server. Is there any solutions?

```
t = paramiko.Transport(('ip', port))
t.connect(username='user', password='pass')
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
fileattr = sftp.lstat(remote_file)
try:
    if stat.S_ISREG(fileattr.st_mode):
        if '.xlsx' in remote_file:
            with sftp.open(remote_file) as f:
                f.prefetch()
                df = pd.read_excel(f,dtype=str,engine='openpyxl',sheet_name=sheet)
                t.close()
                print(df)
except Exception as e:
    t.close()
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reas_excel(f.read())` instead of just `read_excel(f)`. `read_excel()` only reads objects with a `read()` method or file paths.

For the problem of more columns than expected there are 3 options:

1. Modify your excel file so that you do not have absolutely nothing in the blanck cells, not even any kind format. And even though, this method is unpredictable.
2. Read the excel into a dataframe and then filter the columns that you need. Or drop the empty columns like `df.dropna(axis='columns', inplace=True)`
3. Use the `usecols` parameter from `read_excel` like `read_excel(f.read(), usecols="A,C,E:F", ...)`. See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=usecols)

I would recommend option 3.

Comment: [`read_excel` is documented](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to support file-like objects. So it should perfectly work with a file-like object that Paramiko `SFTPClient.open` returns.  And given that Pandas `read_csv` do work with `SFTPClient.open`, I see no reason why `read_excel` won't. `read_excel(f.read())` might work as workaround for (unknown) problems that OP suffer. But  ote that it downloads whole file to memory before parsing. So in the end, you will have whole file in memory twice.  What `read_excel(f)` would not.

Comment: from the documentation: "... By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method, such as a file handle (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO.". That is what I meant in the answer

Comment: I do not see a point of your comment. I wrote that `read_excel` supports file-like objects. Indeed, a file-like object is *an object with [at least] `read` method*. And that's what Paramiko `SFTPClient.open` returns. [Here is a documentation of `SFTPFile` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile) that `SFTPClient.open` returns, including the [`read` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile.read).